# Python 2.7 with pandas to_csv() gives UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode

I am using Python 2.7, and to overcome UTF-8 issues, I am using pandas to_csv method.  The issue is, I am still getting unicode errors, which I dont get when I run the script on my local laptop with python 3 (not an option for batch processing).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(stats_results)

df.to_csv('/home/mp9293q/python_scripts/stats_dim_registration_set_column_transpose.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, doublequote=True, index=False,
          index_label=False, header=False, line_terminator='\n', encoding='utf-8');
```

Gives error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Does the file already exists, or is this snipping creating a new one?

Comment: It already exists, what are you thinking?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be having one of these two problems (or maybe both):-

1. As you mentioned in the comments, the file in which you are trying
   to save **Unicode Data**, already exists. Then there are quite
   likely chances that the destination file, may not have
   **UTF-8/16/32** as it encoding scheme.

   By this I mean, when the file was originally created, it's encoding
   scheme may not be **UTF-8**, it could possibly be **ANSI**. So,
   check whether the destination file's encoding scheme is of **UTF**
   family or not.
2. Encode the Unicode string to UTF-8,
   before storing it in a file. By this I mean, any content that you
   are trying to save to your destination file, if contains Unicode
   text, then it should be first encoded.

   Ex.

   ```
   # A character which could not be encoded via 8 bit ASCII
   Uni_str = u"Ç"

   # Converting the unicode text, into UTF-8 format
   Uni_str = Uni_str.encode("utf-8")
   ```

   The above code works differently in python 2.x and 3.x, the reason
   being that 2.x uses ASCII as default encoding scheme, and 3.x uses
   UTF-8. Another difference between the two is how they treat a string
   after passing it via `encode()`.

   In Python 2.x

   ```
   type(u"Ç".encode("utf-8"))
   ```

   Outputs

   ```
   <type 'str'>
   ```

   In Python 3.x

   ```
   type(u"Ç".encode("utf-8"))
   ```

   Outputs

   ```
   <class 'bytes'>
   ```

   As you can notice, in python 2.x the return type of `encode()` is
   string, but in 3.x it is bytes.

So for your case, I would recommend you to encode each string value containing unicode data in your dataframe using `encode()` before trying to store it in the file.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the detailed response.  The issue is I am reading a 17 million recordset from Oracle into memory - are we saying I have to encode every single value manually before generating the CSV?  The error seems to occur whether the file is new or not.  I tried using dataframe to_csv method, but same issue.  I am using the UTF-8 option to read the data in via the cx_Oracle python library.

Comment: @smackenzie Well, not all values, but only the ones which may contain unicode values (like name, locality etc) **(~In general any string)**. So you can exclude the non string values. Secondly, I have a similar project too in which i had to regularly insert unicode data in files. What I did is, I defined the encoding of the file as `utf-8` when i created the file. Since, then I didn't had to encode the unicode value every time I want to write it to a file. Reason, because python 3.x natively supports UTF-8, so no need for encoding the value, just define the file as UTF-8 and its all.

Comment: I am restricted to 2.7 at the moment, because we dont have a 3.x compatible version of cx_Oracle set up on the cluster.

Comment: @smackenzie If that's the case, I don't think any other method exists out there (at least to my knowledge). Because, Python 2.x is more-or-less hard-wired to work with ASCII and only ASCII. So, the only viable solution to me is to pass each string value via `encode()`